# Is it possible to prevent percent string substitution in python

Tags: python, string, substitution

```
>>> def mod2(n):
...   print 'the remainder is', n % 2
... 
>>> mod2(5)
the remainder is 1
>>> mod2(2)
the remainder is 0
>>> mod2('%d')
the remainder is 2
>>> mod2('%d\rHELLO. I AM A POTATO!')
HELLO. I AM A POTATO!
```

Is there anyway to disable `%` symbol (`operator.mod`) from doing wacky string substitution stuff?  I always use `str.format` if I need anything like that, and would generally rather this string substitution feature didn't exist at all, giving a `TypeError` instead.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm not asking about how I can re-implement `mod2` .. I'm asking if this awkward/unnecessary feature of the language can be disabled - similar to how you can change the behaviour of `/` with `__future__`

Comment: You can't. The `str()` type implements a `__mod__` method to handle the interpolation.

Comment: You can't, it's a feature. ;-) But modulus on a string doesn't make much sense, otherwise. So just "cast" it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't disable it with a switch, no. The `str()` type implements a [`__mod__` method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__mod__) to handle the formatting, it's not that Python special-cased the expression just for strings.

As such, to prevent this you either need to cast the `n` argument to something that is *not* a string (by converting it to `int()` for example), or subclass `str()` to override the `__mod__` method:

```
>>> class noformattingstr(str):
...     def __mod__(self, other):
...         raise TypeError('String formatting using "%" has been deprecated')
... 
>>> noformattingstr('hello world: %d') % 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __mod__
TypeError: String formatting using "%" has been deprecated
```

You can assign this to `__builtins__.str`, but this does *not* mean that all string literals will then use your subclass. You'd have to explicitly cast your `str()` values to `noformattingstr()` instances instead.

Comment: While a nice theoretical solution, using this in practice is a terrible idea.

Comment: Agreed, I can’t believe you seriously suggested monkey-patching built-in types.

Comment: @Lattyware: Absolutely agree, but the OP was asking specifically how to disable it. It's going to be ugly in either direction.

Comment: @poke: It doesn't even work for literals. It'd require casting *each* and *every* literal, not an option either.

Comment: Oh, I never presumed you were posing this as a good solution - just as an example of how awesome Python is and what one can do.

Comment: This is the "answer" I was looking for.  I did not realise that `str` implements `__mod__` method, for something completely unrelated to modulo!  I probably should have left out the silly `mod2` example, because it seems to have distracted everyone else  ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to ensure that `n` is a number, the simplest way, I would argue, is to perform a numeric operation with it beforehand:

```
def mod2(n):
    n - 1
    print 'the remainder is', n % 2
```

This will ensure a `TypeError` will be raised as you cannot take away from a string, while you can from all numeric types.

You may want to encircle it in a try/catch block and raise your own exception which is a little more descriptive of the actual problem.

As another note, it might just be worth being more careful about storing your types of data. While Python is duck typed, it's a little odd to have a situation where a number or a string can be passed in. A note saying it won't handle strings correctly might be the right call.

Answer (score 0):

```
def mod2(n):
    print('the remainder is %d' % (n % 2))

mod2(5)
# the remainder is 1
mod2('%d\rHELLO. I AM A POTATO!')
# TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

Comment: This presumes that all the asker actually wants to do is print the value, which may not be the case.

Comment: I think this is actually a nice trick, but it again won’t work for non-ints.

Answer (score 0):

Cast n with int() in the function.

```
def mod2(n):
    print 'the remainder is', int(n) % 2
```

Comment: This will break for other numeric types though, e.g. `3.14 % 2`.

Comment: That's true. Better solution is to call the method with precasted actual parameter so the function is more reusable. In this case of course the function does not contain cast.

Comment: Besides, it will work for calls like `mod2('123')` which might lead to some unfortunate behaviors (when used in a slightly more complex code). Unless `__doc__` clearly specifies that argument is converted to int when possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know why eumiro removed his answer, but that’s what I would have suggested as well. Except that I would check the type explicitely for unsupported types to keep it open for types that actually support the modulo operator (like floats):

```
def mod2(n):
    if isinstance(n, basestring): # for Py3 use `isinstance(n, str)`
        raise TypeError('unsupported type')
    else:
        print 'the remainder is', n % 2
```

Comment: If you are going to type check a string, just check against `basestr` in 2.x or `str` in 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't want to, even if you could; huge amounts of code out there still uses the `%` string formatting methods, including code in the Python libraries.

The `%` operator compiles to the `BINARY_MODULO` opcode:

```
>>> dis.dis(mod2)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('the remainder is')
              3 PRINT_ITEM          
              4 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              7 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             10 BINARY_MODULO       
             11 PRINT_ITEM          
             12 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

That means that there's no way to prevent string formatting occurring without modifying the parameter; and if you want to allow arbitrary numeric types to work in your code then you need to allow them to handle the modulo operation in their own way, i.e. using the `%` operator.

To check that the argument is of a numeric type, use `numbers`:

```
from number import Number
if not isinstance(n, Number):
    raise TypeError(n)
```

Comment: `BINARY_MODULO` uses the `__mod__` method if present; `str()` implements that method.